# Ubuntu 10.04 как открыть eglibc-2.11.1.tar.xz

Tags: пакет, архивация, ubuntu

Скачал пакет eglibc-source_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.7_all.deb (д.б. исходники с http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/lucid/libs)

Запустил в ubuntu gdebi-gtk, открыл, получил /usr/src/glibc/eglibc-2.11.1.tar.xz

Я надеюсь, что это .tar с исходниками libc.

```
root@avp-ubu1:/usr/src/glibc# tar xzf eglibc-2.11.1.tar.xz 
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Завершение работы с состоянием неисправности с из-за возникших ошибок
root@avp-ubu1:/usr/src/glibc#
```

Вопрос: **как его распаковать ?**

Comment: Не знаю, в чем проблема. Я именно так и распаковываю, и все работает. Может, файл поврежден? Попробуй закачать вариант из Natty http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/eglibc_2.13.orig.tar.gz

Comment: xz-utils не стояли (@andy подсказал), а вообще в man tar для .xz сказано про флаг J (но может tar по z тоже соображает).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo apt-get install xz-utils 
Не?

Comment: Установил. Дальше какие слова набирать ? Мне бы .tar извлечь...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XZ_Utils

Comment: @andy, если знаете, то подскажите конкретно.

Comment: Да, unxz помогло, спасибо. Хорошим советом (если 4 буквы набрать в лом), было бы man -k xz.

Comment: tar Jxvf eglibc-2.11.1.tar.xz

Comment: Спасибо @alexlz, да похоже это те исходники, файл stdlib/msort.c комплексная сортировка (смесь mergesort и quicksort) с интерфейсами qsort и qsort_r.

Это я по поводу своего вопроса об алгоритме qsort в ubuntu.

Comment: Найдена часть исходников linux! (исходники glibc) Ещё немного, и мы сможем найти исходники таинственных binutils! (А там и до ядра недалеко). Хотя всё же хорошо, что перекомпиляция ядра уже не является рутинной операцией.

Comment: @alexlz, IMHO с мотивировкой причин поиска исходников немного ошибаетесь. 

Всегда считал, что qsort в \*nix это quicksort, а тут (ubuntu) заметил другое поведение (невысокая для quicksort скорость, расход памяти, а потом обнаружил устойчивость сортировки), вот и заинтересовался, какой алгоритм используется.

Comment: Могу только извиниться. Но благодаря вопросу узнал, что Debian/Ubuntu положили на glibc (с объяснением причин) и перешли на ветку eglibc.